# Oracle - Database trigger to create a file

Tags: database, oracle, kubernetes, triggers, kubernetes-pvc

We have two scenarios

Scenario 1:

In `table_1` schema, there is `time_created` column that has time of inserting a row.

Database trigger should delete rows that are older than 2 hours.

---

Scenario 2:

On `table_2`, there is `time_created` column that has time of inserting a row and `seq_no` column that has sequence starting from `1` to `9999999` and then roll back.

Database trigger must create a csv file(from `table_2` rows), that satisfies the earliest of any one of the below two conditions:

> 1. Last trigger to create file, exceeded 5 minutes

> 2. Number of existing rows in `table_2` exceeded 500

---

1. 

In scenario 1, Can DB trigger get enabled on `table_1`, every 2 hours?

2.

In scenario 2, Does Oracle DB provide any package that allow to configure those two conditions?

Comment: A *trigger* will execute every time you insert data, and *only* when you insert data. If you want something to run every 2 hours (or any regular interval) then look at scheduled jobs. Sounds like you probably want a scheduled job for your second scenario, too. Where do you plan to create this csv file?

Comment: As pmdba says, you mean a scheduler job, not a trigger. But I would also recommend not trying to schedule a job within the database to export a file (e.g. using utl_file). That's slow and raises security concerns. You're far better off scheduling something in the OS (like a crontab in Unix) that connects via sqlplus and runs a query and spools to a file.

Comment: @PaulW For scenario 1 atleast I can use scheduled job, to delete rows in `table_1`. Does schedule job use some syntax of stored procedures? am new to this..

Comment: @pmdba We would like to create these files in [PVC storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) in Kubernetes cluster.  Oracle database will be hosted(OnPrem) outside kubernetes cluster.

Comment: @overexchange then you will need to follow PaulW's suggestion and use a scheduled client job (e.g. with cron) running sqlplus or something similar to spool an output file. Stored procedures using UTL_FILE can only write to local files on the database server, in directories visible and writable by the Oracle instance process owner.

Comment: @PaulW For scenario 1, if I use [scheduler job](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#ADMIN034), then, Is the job type *stored_procedure*?

Comment: @overexchange No, a Job is a job. A configuration on the database that will run on the specified interval, think of it as an alarm set in your clock for specific intervals or specific time and that alarm will call an action. The job will/can then be configured to call a stored procedure which has the code to do what you need. The provided documentation has many examples check it out.

Comment: You can do a stored procedure (if you create one) or simply a plsql block, either way.